# Live navigation instructions from the HERE app on smartphone

Tags: navigation, here-api, hud, heremaps-android-sdk, heremaps-ios-sdk

Does the SDK (Lite Version) sufficient for an application that prints the live navigation instructions that comes from the phone's app during navigation?
I don't want to calculate any routes, nor display a map.
I want to get the current instruction and distance to the next instruction as a structure so I can print it on another display.

Ex:
**SpeedLimit**  Speed Limit on current location.

**DirDistance** Distance to next instruction.

**RountAbout**  At the roundabout take the N exit.

**LeftTurn**    In N meters turn Left.

**RightTurn**   In N meters turn right.

**SlightLeft**  In N meters turn slightLeft.

**SlightRight** In N meters turn slightRight.

and so on as it shows on top of the app...
What is the API required for this operation?

I added a picture to show what I'm looking for:
[Instructions marked in red circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prj4A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to have guidance functionality. Guidance functionality is not supported by the Lite Editions of the HERE SDK. Instead, you may look for the 4.x HERE SDK (Navigate Edition) which is available for three platforms, [Android](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate), [iOS](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-navigate), or [Flutter](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate). All these editions support the set of instructions you look for.

You can also checkout this open source project on GitHub, that shows how it can look like: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-ref-app-flutter.